# My 2011 iMac's internal Superdrive won't take a disc

Tags: mac, dvd, 23.10, optical

I have tried to use `sg_raw` with no avail...

```
root@iMac:/dev# sg_raw /dev/sr0 ea 00 00 00 00 00 01
NVMe Result=0x0
```

Trying to run `sg_raw -r 1k` gives me this output.

```
root@iMac:/dev# sg_raw -r 1k /dev/sr0 12 00 00 00 00 60 00
NVMe Result=0x0
Received 1024 bytes of data:
 00     00 00 05 32 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ...2............
 10     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
 20     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
```

(note I cut off the rest since it was all 00.)

I do not have macOS installed, but I still do have the recovery partition...

I also did try to `eject`... the drive made a tiny noise but nothing happened... I assume there is no disc inside.

##### What else can I try to do to get the drive working?

Comment: What is the internal superdrive? Is it like a DVD drive?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yes...